# how to add library compilation to numpy.distutils.core?

Tags: python, numpy, setup.py

I'm trying make setup.py for my tiny module, which uses numpy. To compile this module I need extra library which locates in same directory

```
ls -l audiotools 
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rth rth 4405 Sep  9 10:58 audiotools.c
drwxr-xr-x 6 rth rth 4096 Sep  9 11:13 libresample-0.1.3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rth rth  741 Sep  9 11:56 setup.py
```

So I need add something in setup.py which will call configure and make in libresample-0.1.3 and then add 'libresample.a' to the linker command.

I've tried used add_library, but it requires just source files but not whole source directory. How I can do it?

This doesn't work.

```
def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
        import numpy
        from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration

        config = Configuration('audiotools',parent_package,top_path)
        config.add_extension('audiotools', ['audiotools.c'])
        config.add_library('libresample',['libresample.a'])
        return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
        setup(
                name = "audiotools",
                version='0.01',
                description='Python wrapper for GNU libresample-0.1.3 and reader of Wave 24bit files',
                author='Ruben Tikidji-Hamburyan, Timur Pinin',
                author_email='rth@nisms.krinc.ru, timpin@rambler.ru',
                configuration=configuration
        )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know this is quite a hassle. The usual approach is to basically require the lib to be installed on the system as a shared lib.

*pyzmq* do some kind of attempt on this, but it aint trivial:
https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Wow! It is really complicated stuff.... Probably my setup.py will be bigger than module :(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way which I have found is to use os.system. But it isn't look well for me.

```
def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
        import numpy
        from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration

        config = Configuration('audiotools',parent_package,top_path)
        config.add_extension('audiotools', ['audiotools.c'],
                extra_link_args=[os.getcwd()+'/libresample-0.1.3/libresample.a'], 
                depends=['libresample-0.1.3/libresample.a'],

        return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
        import os
        os.system('pushd libresample-0.1.3 && ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC && make &&popd')
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
        setup(
                name = "audiotools",
                version='0.01',
                description='Python wrapper for GNU libresample-0.1.3 and reader Wave 24 files',
                author='Ruben Tikidji-Hamburyan, Timur Pinin',
                author_email='rth@nisms.krinc.ru, timpin@rambler.ru',
                configuration=configuration
        )
```